# Windows registry migration

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I have a 32 bit VC++ application and its registry is created under 32 bit registry hive :

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\<company>\<product>
```

Now I'm migrating to 64 bit version of my application and I want to migrate all the keys and values under 32 bit registry hive of my application to 64 bit registry hive, e.g.:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\<company>\<product>
```

Does Microsoft provides any feature to accomplish this?

Kindly provide any other way to do this other than manually replacing `\Wow6432Node` in keys path of an exported `.reg`, then importing it.

Comment: It should search for old keys automatically when accessing the 64-bit value. So a 64-bit program should access the 32-bit keys and convert them automatically. So, just launch the 64-bit program and test that it already works.

Comment: No, It isn't working. When I launch the 64 bit app, new registry is created but it contains very few keys. Also My configuration in 32 bit is not replicated at all.

Comment: This is handled automatically, if the application is 64-bit it’s impossible to use the 32-bit location, so just make the application 64-bit. How you do that is better asked on SO.

Comment: Does the Windows SDK offer tools for this? Has [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/) been referenced?

Comment: There is no other way than editing the exported `.reg` file.

Comment: "Kindly provide any other way to do this other than manually replacing \Wow6432Node in keys path of an exported .reg, then importing it." You have a method that *might* work, but don't care to use it.

Comment: As reg files are text, a simple find and replace may be all you need to do. Have you tried this yet?